# Proving relation between different Green's functions at equilibrium (book: Mahan's Many-Particle Physics)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

In second chapter of Mahan, Dyson equation (Eq#$2.159$) for different Green's functions (GF) in real space is derived
$$
G^{r(a)} =G^{r(a)}_0\otimes[1+\Sigma^{r(a)}\otimes G^{r(a)}]\\
G^{<(>)}=[1+G^r\otimes\Sigma^r]\otimes G^{<(>)}_0\otimes [1+\Sigma^a\otimes G^a]+G^r\otimes \Sigma^{<(>)}\otimes G^a \\
G^t=[1+G^r\otimes \Sigma^r]\otimes G^t_0\otimes [1+\Sigma^a\otimes G^a]+G^r\otimes \Sigma^{\bar{t}}\otimes G^a
$$
here $\otimes =\int d^3x \int dt$ and all GF are in real space and time. Next they consider these GF for equilibrium system and Fourier transform them. After Fourier transform, there are no integrations and we have quantities which are variable of only $(k,\omega)$, i.e., we have algebraic relations
$$
G^{r(a)} =G^{r(a)}_0 [1+\Sigma^{r(a)} G^{r(a)}]\\
G^{<(>)}=[1+G^r \Sigma^r] G^{<(>)}_0 [1+\Sigma^a G^a]+G^r  \Sigma^{<(>)} G^a \\
G^t=[1+G^r \Sigma^r] G^t_0 [1+\Sigma^a G^a]+G^r \Sigma^{\bar{t}} G^a
$$
After that, the author writes that we get the following relations for GF (Eq#$2.160$)
$$
G^{r(a)}(k,\omega) =\frac{1}{\omega-\epsilon_k+\Sigma^{r(a)}(k,\omega)}\\
G^{<}(k,\omega)=in_F(\omega) A(k,\omega)\\
G^{>}(k,\omega)=-i(1-n_F(\omega)) A(k,\omega)\\
A(k,\omega)=\frac{2\Gamma}{\sigma^2+\Gamma^2}\quad ; \quad \Gamma=-Im{\Sigma^r}\quad ; \quad  \sigma= \omega-\epsilon_k-Re\Sigma^{r}
$$
Author has also given exact relations for $G^{r,a,<,>,t}_0$ as
$$
G^{r(a)}_0(k,\omega) =\frac{1}{\omega-\epsilon_k\pm\eta}\\
G^<_0(k,\omega)=2\pi i n_F(\epsilon_k) \delta(\omega-\epsilon_k)\\
G^>_0(k,\omega)=-2\pi i [1-n_F(\epsilon_k)] \delta(\omega-\epsilon_k)\\
G^{t}(k,\omega) =G^r_0+G^<_0
$$
By using these relations, I was able to derive relation for $G^{r(a)}(k,\omega)$. Can someone please help me in proving the relations for $G^{<}$ and $G^{<}$?